# need to compare 3 variables and need to print highest of those three variables

Tags: shell-script, csh

```
set func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2R_WNS = `grep -i Reg2Reg $tile/../sta/func/sta-max-func-ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst/reports/pba_proc_qor.rpt | awk '{print $2}'`

set func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_M2R_WNS = `grep -i Mem2Reg $tile/../sta/func/sta-max-func-ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst/reports/pba_proc_qor.rpt | awk '{print $2}'`

set func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2M_WNS = `grep -i Reg2Mem $tile/../sta/func/sta-max-func-ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst/reports/pba_proc_qor.rpt | awk '{print $2}'`
set x = `awk '{print $func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2R_WNS + "0" }'`
set y = `awk '{print $func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_M2R_WNS + "0"}'`
set z = `awk '{print $func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2M_WNS + "0"}'`

if (($x >= $y) && ($x >= $z)) then 
#unsetenv func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2A_WNS 
setenv func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2A_WNS `awk '{print  $x }'`

else if (($y >= $x) && ($y >= $z)) then 
#unsetenv func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2A_WNS
setenv func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2A_WNS `awk '{print $y }'`

else if (($z >= $x) && ($z >= $y)) then 
#unsetenv func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2A_WNS
setenv func_ssgnp_0p675v_m40c_typical_Ccworst_R2A_WNS `awk '{print $z }'`

endif
```

can you please help me with this.

Comment: Why do you assign `\`awk '{print  $x }'\`` to the variable? You just assign `$x` or `$y` or `$z`.

Comment: Do you really, really need to write this script in csh? [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). Also, please [edit] your question and i) explain what you are trying to do, how you run this, what result you are expecting, ii) explain how it fails.

Comment: In particular these `awk` commands (1) will not return, because you don't specify an operand (like a file to process), and (2) even if, they would simply ignore your variable assignments and print the input (whatever that may then be) unchanged, because inside single quotes, variable substitution is disabled, so `awk` will see `$x` as a reference to the `x`-th field of the line, with `x` being 0 as it isn't inizialized _inside the `awk` program_.